# Logout icon avec DrawerNavigation (react native)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

how i add icon to drawer navigation item using react native ?

```
const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
    'Rendez Vous' : RendezVous,
    'Parcours de soin': ParcoursDeSoin,
    'Ordonnances' : Ordonnances,
    'Analyses' : Analyses,
    'Profil' : Profil,
    'A Propos': APropos,
    'Logout ': Login
```

Comment: see example https://snack.expo.io/@lekgwaraj/createdrawernavigator-tyling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under your login screen route config, use `drawerIcon` under `navigationOptions` to add your icon

```
Login: {
  screen: Login,
  navigationOptions: {
    drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
      <Icon name="ios-home" size={20} color={tintColor} />
    ),
  },
},
```

[demo](http://snack.expo.io/@lekgwaraj/createdrawernavigator-tyling)